# Polarisation of vector fields

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, polarization, vector-fields

I'm reading "No-nonsense quantum field theory" by Jakob Schwichtenberg. On page 76 of the book the author introduces the idea that vector fields $A_u(x_u)$, which are object that assigns a vector to each point in spacetime, can be written as a product:
$$A_u (x_u) = \epsilon_u \times f(x_u)$$

where $\epsilon_u$ with $\epsilon_u \epsilon^u = -1$ denotes the "internal structure" and $f(x_u)$ is a function that denotes the spacetime structure by assigning the field strength at that point. The author argues that the vectors $\epsilon_u$ can be written as a linear combination of basis vectors $\epsilon_u^i$, claiming that the $\epsilon_u$ are usually denoted as **polarisation vectors** and that to find any possible polarisation it is sufficient to find appropriate linear combinations of basis vectors.
To illustrate this point further the author gives the following example  which illustrates what does it mean for a field to be polarised.
[image]

Could someone explain intuitively what does this mean? In particular, why would can $\epsilon_u$ be regarded as polarisation vectors and what is meant by (linear) polarisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with what polarization means.

When talking about polarization we always consider transverse waves. That is waves that oscillate perpendicular to the direction of propagation. Electro-Magnetic waves in vacuum would be an example of this*. (Of course a general vector field can have any polarization that is either time-like, longitudinal or transverse. For simplicity I will however focus on EM-waves in vacuum.)

Obviously there is not only one direction perpendicular to the propagation axis ($x_3$ in the graph you supplied). But there are infinitely many directions/polarizations $\epsilon_\mu$ which satisfy the property:

$\epsilon_\mu \cdot x_3 = 0$

We can just take one particular $\epsilon_\mu$ and rotate it around $x_3$ to get another perpendicular vector. The wave could equally well oscillate in the $x_2$ direction. We can use this vector $\epsilon_\mu$ to describe the polarisation of an EM-wave and we can even define a (physical) polarization basis

$\epsilon^1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \cr 1 \cr 0 \cr 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad
\epsilon^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \cr 0 \cr 1 \cr 0 \end{pmatrix},$

from which we can build every possible polarization by linear combination: $\epsilon_\mu = a \epsilon^1_\mu + b \epsilon^2_\mu$.

Following the example you provided:

- We take the wave to **propagate** in the $x_3$ direction: $\to f(x_\mu) = \sin(x_3)$**
- We take the wave to **oscillate** in the $\pm x_1$ direction: $\to \epsilon_\mu = \begin{pmatrix}0\cr 1\cr 0\cr 0\end{pmatrix}$
- So in total our wave is given by: $A_\mu\left(x_\mu\right)= \epsilon_\mu f(x_\mu) = \begin{pmatrix}0\cr \sin(x_3)\cr 0\cr 0\end{pmatrix}$

**Note that we cannot talk about the polarization of sound waves (in liquids), as these are longitudinal waves. So they always oscillate in the direction of motion.*

***We could also make it depend on $x_0$, i.e. on time.*

Comment: great post, but i think you are being too categorical. There is nothing wrong with longitudinal polarization. It can even be mixed transverse and longitudinal, e.g. electromagnetic waves in plasma

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I simply chose to talk about EM waves (in vacuum) to give a practical example. For a general vector field of course all polarizations are valid. I am going to add this in the main post.

It is very interesting that there are longitudinal em waves in plasma, I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with classical electromagnetism?

A field can be scalar. In which case there is a function that assigns a value to any position in space and time - this we then call field.

More generally it could be a function that assigns a vector or even a tensor to any space and time position. This would be the vector(tensor) field. In some common cases the general case of function assigning a vector to every position in space and time, can be simplified, because it always assigns the same vector, but multiplied by a different scalar constant. In this case we call such vector, the polarization vector.

Linear polarization refers to how the polarization vector is defined, the linear polarization vector does not depend on position in space. Compare it to radial polarization vector, i.e. a vector pointing from the origin, to the point in question. The radial vector is well-defined at all points in space, but changes as a function of space.